# Dropdown list of available posts for post editing

Tags: admin, dropdown

I have posts of two different categories that I can't easily relate.
categories are: instructors and class categories (like aerobic, weights etc.)
I would like to tie instructors to class posts NOT class types.

Ideally from the **post edit screen**, I would like a dropdown of all instructors  available from the class postings and then be able to select an instructor.

Here is the class listing page http://howlingwolfmedia.com/site3/classes/classlist/
You can also see the instructor's listed under > classes > instructors
I'd like the selected name to then show in the 'instructor' column.

code for the classlist table: http://pastebin.com/tNScDVxW

class postings fall under child cat 5-10 of parent cat id: 4
instructors cat id: 4
these are standard (not custom) post types

This must in some way alter the admin part of the site and I'm not familiar with coding for that... nor am I well versed in mysql coding etc.

Comment: Try looking for [Advanced Custom Field](http://advancedcustomfields.com/) WordPress Plugin

Comment: Before I go down a rabbit's hole here... would this plugin work with existing standard posts or do they need to be custom post types. The site's already created and the cross ref would need to apply to standard (NON custom) post types currently using categorization.

Comment: Yes, it support default post type and it's free of cost.

Comment: OK.  I'll look into it. BTW what specifically should i search for if i want to install directly from console. 'Advanced custom fields' pulled 500+ results. Is it ElliottCondon Advanced Custom Fields 4.3.4? Also I'm using latest WP 3.8... is it compatible?

Comment: So far the plugin ref'd above looks promising. Just gotta figure out how to hook the field group to the post. Maybe custom coding is needed b/c i applied the rule but as of now... all i see on the post is label 'custom fields' with name 'select' and value... not the field i created. Still reading.

Comment: No custom coding should be need. When you edit/create a field group, there's option to set the field group for chosen post type and a lot of amazing features. You just keep digging it.

Comment: Getting there!!~~ Got the relational part working. Now playing with adding code in template for display. This is very cool!! Thanks!

Comment: Well the back end works and the dashboard interface allows me to pull the instructors for each class. I applied to first 4 classes of this page: http://howlingwolfmedia.com/site3/classes/classlist/
 but it's not pulling the right values (getting a null return) <br> 
`<p ><?php the_field('instructor_select', 'category_3'); ?> </p>`

Answer (score 0):

OK!! I found the solution on this page: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/relationship/ using Basic loop without setup_postdata worked like a dream!! GREAT PLUGIN!! Will review for others. Great documentation and geared towards the less than hard core developers. Thanks Shazzad for the referral!